# Cannot add repository key

Tags: 12.04

I just installed my new laptop with ubuntu 12.04 and when I'm trying to add key, there is a "network unreachable" error.

```
william@ubuntu:~$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
gpg: requesting key CD2EFD2A from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Network is unreachable
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Network is unreachable
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I'm so sure the keyserver is not down, because I tried it again at my old laptop running ubuntu 11.04

```
william@william:~$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
gpg: requesting key CD2EFD2A from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key CD2EFD2A: "Percona MySQL Development Team <mysql-dev@percona.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: The keyserver is reachable from my PC. Sounds like a network problem on your side.

Comment: No, my network is fine. Can't you see I have tried it on my old laptop? They are on the same network.

Comment: @WilliamAnthony from what it looks you already had the key on the old laptop so the key was not processed (read downloaded) and so it didnt give you the error. Well i dont know what is causing the problem but u can try the answer given below. Just find out where the gpg keys are stored and then transfer them to the new laptop. Also it cannot be a bug because adding gpg keys works for others.

Comment: @VitalieCiubotaru how did you check if the keyserver is working. this is just for my info

Comment: I did not say it works. I just said that it's reachable. I `ping`ed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

May be off topic for you. Can you add it via Synaptic Package manager.

[image]